# Height in background-image inline style

Tags: css

I would like to create text on image like parallax. And, I use background-image inline style to show the image. How can I set height of this image? It could be the image's height. But, my image shows the height relates with the text lines. For example, I have two lines, my image height will show only two lines height.

If I set height in pixel (height:400px), it works, but how's about the responsive design? Is it the best practices? Please advise. Below is my css style. Thank you in advance.

```
background-image: url(http://localhost:31903/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/corn-field-440338_1920-1024x680.jpg);
background-attachment: fixed;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
background-size: 100% auto;
```

I use wp_add_inline_style to style the image

```
function metabox_inline_style( $post_id ) {

$MyOptions = get_option('MyOptions');

    $custom_metabox_css = '';

        foreach ( $MyOptions as $key => $MyOption ) {
if (isset($MyOption['background-image']) ) { 
                $custom_metabox_css .= "#parallax-shortcode-{$key}.parallax {";
                $custom_metabox_css .= (isset($MyOption['background-image']) ? 'background-image:url('.$MyOption['background-image'].');' :'');
                $custom_metabox_css .= (isset($MyOption['background-image']) ? 'background-attachment: fixed;' :'');
                $custom_metabox_css .= (isset($MyOption['background-image']) ? 'background-repeat: no-repeat;' :'');
                $custom_metabox_css .= (isset($MyOption['background-image']) ? 'background-position: center;' :'');
                $custom_metabox_css .= (isset($MyOption['background-image']) ? 'background-size: 100% 100%;' :'');
                $custom_metabox_css .= (isset($MyOption['background-image']) ? 'position: absolute;' :'');
                $custom_metabox_css .= (isset($MyOption['background-image']) ? 'height: 100%;' :'');

                $custom_metabox_css .= "}";
            }
        }

        wp_add_inline_style( 'custom-style', $custom_metabox_css);   
 }

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'metabox_inline_style');
```

Comment: show some more code please, use a jsfiddle to construct your example

Comment: @joyBlanks [link]http://jsfiddle.net/WilliamN/s10x5czn/

Answer (score 0):

Probably without setting height of div, background image wraps around containing text only
Its possible through setting height only. To make responsive put style `height: 100%;`

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/fovq792h/)

Comment: Thanks for you answer. After I test with Fiddle, it looks nice. When I change my real code, the position:absolute makes my image disappear. One more information, I use wp_add_inline_style function to create inline style.

Comment: Now, I solve this problem by using padding: 20% 0; Hope it is correct way.